# How to move turtles in patches with different colors

Tags: netlogo

Sorry, I am yet beginner with Netlogo. I have a problem with the primitive "n-of". I have 100 individuals in the world. From 100 individuals, I would like to move 52 individuals in roads and 48 in fields.

```
let turtle-%-in-roads 52
let turtle-%-in-fields 48

create-turtles 100 

ask n-of round ( (100 * turtle-%-in-roads) / 100 ) turtles [  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = white] ]
print count turtles-on patches with [pcolor = white] ;; give 52 OK

ask n-of round ( (100 * turtle-%-in-fields) / 100 ) turtles [  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = brown] ]
  print count turtles-on patches with [pcolor = brown] ;; give 73 

 print count turtles-on patches with [pcolor = white] ;; give 27 
 print count turtles-on patches with [pcolor = brown] ;; give 73
```

I don't understand why I have 27 individuals instead of 52 in roads and 73 individuals instead of 48 in fields ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first ask is moving 52 turtles to road successfully, but then the second ask is taking some of those turtles and moving them to fields. You want the second ask to only affect turtles not on roads. So:

```
ask n-of round ( (100 * turtle-%-in-fields) / 100 ) turtles with [ pcolor != white ] [
  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = brown]
]
```